# Processing error with processing-arduino examples

Tags: serial, processing-lang

I have followed the instructions to run the [Arduino processing examples](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing) but with no success.

Always `import processing.serial.*;` does not name a type. Which is perhaps a library (processing-arduino) related error.

My sketch is a sketch that comes with processing-arduino library.

I have searched for a long time with no solution. Any suggestion?

Errors:

```
arduino_output:28: error: 'import' does not name a type
arduino_output:30: error: 'import' does not name a type
arduino_output:32: error: 'Arduino' does not name a type
arduino_output:34: error: 'color' does not name a type
arduino_output:35: error: 'color' does not name a type
arduino_output:37: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
arduino_output.pde: In function 'void setup()':
arduino_output:42: error: 'size' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:45: error: 'Arduino' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:45: error: 'println' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:50: error: 'arduino' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:50: error: expected type-specifier before 'Arduino'
arduino_output:50: error: expected `;' before 'Arduino'
arduino_output:58: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
arduino_output.pde: In function 'void draw()':
arduino_output:62: error: 'off' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:62: error: 'background' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:63: error: 'on' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:63: error: 'stroke' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:66: error: 'values' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:66: error: 'Arduino' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:66: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
arduino_output:66: error: expected `)' before numeric constant
arduino_output:67: error: 'fill' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:69: error: 'fill' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:71: error: 'rect' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output.pde: In function 'void mousePressed()':
arduino_output:77: error: 'mouseX' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:80: error: 'values' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:80: error: 'Arduino' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:80: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
arduino_output:80: error: expected `)' before numeric constant
arduino_output:81: error: 'arduino' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:81: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
arduino_output:82: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
arduino_output:82: error: expected `;' before numeric constant
arduino_output:84: error: 'arduino' was not declared in this scope
arduino_output:84: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
arduino_output:85: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
arduino_output:85: error: expected `;' before numeric constant
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ibrahim. Can you edit your answer to include the example code? Is it the example that is near the bottom of the page that you link to? Also, you may like to take a [tour](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site.

Comment: Which processing-arduino package version are you using, processing-arduino.zip or processing2-arduino.zip? Which version of the processing application are you using? Are you using it with the correct version of Processing?

Answer (score 2):

> Note: I am testing this on OS X, so my paths may differ slightly from yours.

I have managed to reproduce your issue, by *incorrectly* copying the `arduino` directory, from the unzipped [processing2-arduino.zip](http://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Interfacing/processing2-arduino.zip) package, to the `libraries` directory under the `Arduino` directory in my home directory, thus

```
/Users/user/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduino
```

Then opening the Arduino IDE and running the `arduino_output` example, via the menu, `File -> Sketchbook -> Libraries -> Arduino -> arduino_output`. When I hit the compile button, in the Arduino IDE, the compiler throws up the exact same errors that you describe in your question.

However this is not the correct usage of this package. This package is intended to be used in conjunction with the **Processing** application, *not* the **Arduino IDE**. You should download [Processing](https://processing.org/) and then follow the [instructions](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing) again:

> 1. Unzip the library and copy the "arduino" folder into the "libraries" sub-folder of your Processing Sketchbook. (You can find
>      the location of your Sketchbook by opening the Processing Preferences.
>      If you haven't made a "libraries" sub-folder, create one.)

Thus, on OS X, the path should now be

```
/Users/user/Documents/Processing/libraries/arduino
```

However, as usual, the documentation on the Arduino website leaves a lot to be desired. Pay careful attention to the following paragraph if you are running OS X or Linux:

> Note: if you run Linux, you need to change `Arduino.jar` into
>   `arduino.jar`, because Linux is case sensitive and it does not work if
>   you don't change this letter (Arduino.jar is in the folder "library"
>   of this Processing Library).

So,

```
/Users/user/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduino/library/Arduino.jar
```

becomes

```
/Users/user/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduino/library/arduino.jar
```

Relaunch the Processing application. `File -> Examples...`, opens up a window, scroll down to `Contributed Libraries`, open that, open `Arduino (Firmata)`, open the `arduino_output` example. Hit the **Run** button, and after compiling you should see the window below:

[image: arduino_output window]

HTH.